# Optimistics and pessimistics village

Tags: probability

In village there are two kinds of people: pessimistics and optimistics.

optimistics- answering "YES" for $70\%$ from the questions and "NO" for $30\%$ from the questions .

pessimistics- answering "NO" for $80\%$ from the questions and "YES" for $20\%$ from the questions

In a survey that made in the village they found that $60\%$ answerd "YES" and $40\%$ answerd "NO"

> Find the pessimistics presentage and the optimistics presentage

---

**My attempt:**

I think that this is related to [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem)

Let $\cal O$ be the optimistics presentage, and let $\cal O^{c}$ be the pessimistics presentage so we are looking for

P$(\cal O)-?$ and P$(\cal O^{c})-?$

let $Y$ denote the event that the person answerd "YES" so

$\text{P}[Y]=\text{P}[Y|\cal O^{c}]$ $  \text{P}[\cal O^{c}]+$ $\text{P}[Y|\cal \cal O^{c}]$ $  \text{P}[\cal O]=$$0.2\times\text{P}[\cal O^{c}]$$+0.7\times (1-\text{P}[\cal O^{c}])$$=0.6$

and now this is equation with one unknown $\Longrightarrow \text{P}[\cal O^{c}]$$=0.2$ therefore there are $\bbox[yellow]{80\%}$ optimistics and $\bbox[yellow]{20\%}$ pessimistics

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: Yes it looks correct.